# time under calendar?

Tags: 20.04, time, gnome-shell-extension

Here is my desktop. Is there any Gnome extension to put the time underneath the calendar ? I do believe that I have seen it before, just once.[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is actually functionality you can attain by installing GNOME Clocks. You can do this by finding GNOME Clocks in Ubuntu Software, or you can manually install the `gnome-clocks` package with `sudo apt install gnome-clocks`. Once you have it installed, add a world clock to the list, and it should appear under the calendar. You may need to restart the shell (you can do this by pressing `Alt`+`F2`, typing `r`, and then pressing `Enter`, or you can log out and then back in.) in order to see these changes.

[image: My Notification Area After Installing]

Comment: Thanks !  I had to deleted Gnome Clocks from App-store. Then I reinstalled from command line and it works. Thanks agian.

Comment: Fantastic to hear! Was hoping that was the proper one for you. If possible, be sure to mark the question as solved so others have an easier time hunting down similar solutions :D

Answer (score 0):

! I had to deleted Gnome Clocks from App-store. Then I reinstalled from command line and it works. Thanks agian.